# Send message and notification to Google Home like Disney

Tags: actions-on-google

I made a Google Action to play "Betrayal at House on the Hill" 
In a nutshell:

- People ask to play a game
- Then decide to move from room A to room B to room C
- They can perform actions throught a WebChat

The problem is that Google works on a request/response mechanism

- There is no multiple message like "You see something" "Then you see an other thing"
- There is no "notification" features when something happend "soouuund" so I made a kludge workaround with a PiZero that cast audio to the Home (works for only one user with an horrible beep)

**Questions:**

- Is there a better way to perform multiple messages
- Is there a better way to send notification

[Disney did something like that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH7HI2BW6aE) but I can't figure how they stream audio and push multiple events. Is there some kind of API ETA ?

A [little blog post on my experiement here](https://blog.encausse.net/2018/11/01/halloween-vocal-assistant/).

Comment: I think Disney is doing something custom that isn't available to developers more broadly.